# Is the /proc/[pid]/attr directory always created even if SELinux is not available?

Tags: ubuntu, selinux

I have two machines, a standard Intel-based Ubuntu and a Jetson Xavier, which both have a `/proc/self/attr/current` file. However, the one on the Jetson computer doesn't seem to work:

Here is the output on my standard Intel based Ubuntu:

```
$ xxd /proc/self/attr/current
00000000: 756e 636f 6e66 696e 6564 0a              unconfined.
```

However, it looks like I'm getting an error on the Jetson (ARM based):

```
$ xxd /proc/self/attr/current
xxd: Invalid argument
```

Looking around, it seems to be a file which is part of the SELinux extension and I would assume that it's not installed on the Jetson. But then, why would that file appear under `/proc` if not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entries in `/proc/self/attr` were initially added for SELinux, but they aren’t specific to SELinux — they are used for various security modules. `/proc/self/attr` is enabled if [`CONFIG_SECURITY`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.9/source/security/Kconfig#L22) is enabled; if no security module is selected, attempting to access any of the files in that directory will return `EINVAL`, “Invalid argument”.

I don’t know the reason why the files are listed even though they are inaccessible; that’s always been the case for these particular files, so it might be considered as baked-in behaviour, unchangeable since it’s effectively part of the API that the kernel provides to user-space.